# Evaluating Elo rating on a per move basis

Tags: elo, evaluation

I've been a Chess.com user for a little over 3 years now. I play EVERY day, usually have anywhere from 10 to 50 games going on any single day.

Since I've started, my rating has only gone up about 150 points. For the past 6 months, my Elo has stayed fairly close to 1400.

I know Chess.com has the feature of evaluating the games that I've played and suggests what I did wrong, but I have to request all of those games to be reviewed.

Is there another tool/app that can evaluate the strength of individual moves during each and every game, that would tell me the "strength" of the move? For example, if I stupidly put my queen in a position where the opponent can take it, then that's a blunder and would be rated very poorly.

Or, is there a way to automate all of the Chess.com games to be reviewed by the engine to determine how I did in each?

Comment: It's completely(!) offtopic but...if you spent 3 years getting up to 1400 chess.com's then you should probably change something. You need a coach, books or another kind of solid training. Playing those games doesn't help much. Just a good advice:)

Comment: @user3447603 probably a valid statement :)

Comment: If you want you can share a game or two with me, I'll take a look at 'em in free time

Comment: Pick games that you believe have the highest quality and post them here for analysis. Quality games are games with no or very little mistakes / blunders. It has to be the game where yo believed you played very well. Those are most important to analyze for now. The rest will come later. Just an advice.

Comment: It's absolutely impossible to evaluate Elo based on a single move. Your chess strength depends on a whole plan and the series of moves that you make to commit your action. A single move doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: @ganders A bit off topic, but consider reading books and playing classical over the board games and go to training sessions in real life with other players at your local chess club. This would develop your skills and strength much faster.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff is it possible to just post my Chess.com games here? I've never worked with the PGN things...

Comment: @ganders: Go through [this](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/questions/279/tool-used-to-create-chess-analysis-interactive-diagrams-in-many-chess-stack-exch/280#280) post on Meta. If you need further help leave another comment. If you fail to cope with all of this, try to provide link to the game **but leave me a comment if you do this so I can edit it properly into this site's PGN viewer**. That's all for now, hopefully we shall "speak" again. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there another tool/app that can evaluate the strength of individual moves during each and every game, that would tell me the "strength" of the move?

To be able to evaluate the strength of individual moves, one needs to estimate the difficulty level of the position. This estimation rests on two ingredients: the ability to evaluate the position (almost) perfectly, and a sample of responses for that position from a pool of players with different strength. This is thus an empirical question.

For tactical training, there are straightforward implementations, such as this one:

http://chesstempo.com/user-guide/en/tacticRatingSystem.html

You can add to the accuracy of a solution a time element:

http://chess.emrald.net/time.php

For *any* kind of position, I believe it's still an open problem.

---

A related question is the *optimality* of play. To that effect, Guid & Bratko did an interesting study:

> The basis for their evaluation was the difference between the position values resulting from the moves played by the human chess player and the moves chosen as best by the chess program Crafty. They compared the average number of errors in the player's game. Opening moves were excluded, in an attempt to negate the progress in chess opening theory.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_top_chess_players_throughout_history

But such study cannot estimate the strength of a player as requested by the querent. It can only evaluate optimality of play, and order players according to this evaluation. This does not give ELO or complexity of any given move.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such tools exist and they are called chess engines. Look at [stockfish](http://stockfishchess.org/), [houdini](http://www.cruxis.com/chess/houdini.htm) and [rybka](http://www.rybkachess.com/) there are a lot of [GUIs](http://www.playwitharena.com/) (graphical user interfaces for them). They will report inaccuracies, mistakes and blunders and will show you better lines.

Nonetheless you will be able to automate this process, but the question is 'what will you do' when the engine will analyse your ~ 33.000 games? To actually get something from this analysis - you need to go step by step through a game and make some thinking. So I would rather forget about all those games (may be selecting a few that you think are super cool) and start analyse new games that you will play.

Also irrelevant to the question, but as suggested by others learning chess and playing chess is completely different (also might sound the same). I have seen many players who play tens of games per day (mostly 1-3 minutes, where half of the moves are completely random). They randomly win/draw/lose, but stay on the same rating, because they do not learn from their mistakes.

From my own experience (which basically means nothing) I was staying at the same 1400 rating for 4 month randomly playing games. I also thought that this might help, but it did not. Then I started to analyse my games and played longer games (10 minutes), play puzzles and learn openings. I played at maximum 4 games per day and in 6 months I was able to boost it to 1800 and improve it even further later. Take a look at [my answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/6318/703) to see some insights how you can advance your game.

Comment: But... the question is on how to evaluate Elo per move. Your answer is more about how to improve chess in general. This doesn't answer anything in the question at all.

Comment: @StudentT have you read my first 2 paragraphs? I think I clearly speak about how to evaluate it and what to use to evaluate it. I also describe why in my opinion it will not help. Yes, last 2 paragraphs are how to improve the game, but I DO answer his question. Please read more careful.